# Confusion about PCR

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology

I seem to be getting two different answers from my book and my teacher about PCR.

1. Does PCR require a double stranded piece of DNA that you are tryig to replicate, or does it require a circular piece of DNA (i.e. a plasmid)?

   I believe that when we were doing the experiments, we used a plasmid.
2. Also, I can't seem to find a source which explains how PCR works when you are also introducing a mutation at the same time.

   We used different primers to introduce a mutation during the PCR, but I am still very confused as to how the primer could bind when the nucleotide sequence is not exactly matching.

Answer (score 4):

> For PCR, does PCR require a double stranded piece of DNA that you are trying to replicate, or does it require a circular piece of DNA (i.e. a plasmid).

Circular DNA is not required.  Double-stranded DNA is, but keep in mind that if you start with a single-stranded DNA that (i) can be primed by an appropriate 'foward' primer and (ii) contains the reverse complement of a 'reverse' primer binding site (**i.e. contains the sequence of a reverse primer, see comments**), then during the first cycle of PCR, a double-stranded DNA will be created from the single-stranded DNA.

In fact, circular DNA, while generally a viable substrate for PCR, is less good than linear dsDNA under some extreme conditions, especially if it highly supercoiled, because strand displacement by DNA polymerase becomes more difficult.

> Also, I can't seem to find a source wheich explains how PCR works when you are also introducing a mutation at the same time. We used different primers to introduce a mutation during the PCR, but I am stilll very confused as to how the primer could bind when the nucleotide sequence is not exactly matching?

The thermodynamics of primer binding is a complex but fairly well-understood subject.  Each nucleotide in the primer that matches the target DNA sequence will provide favorable enthalpic (and entropic) interactions with the target, favoring binding.  These favorable interactions are even more favored if the nucleotide's neighbors in the DNA chain also match.  There is a general entropic penalty for binding because the degrees of freedom in a single dsDNA molecule are way lower than in two ssDNA molecules.  Essentially, once there are enough matching sites between a primer and a target DNA, binding will be favorable (and this transition point will depend on temperature, with higher temperature always dis-favoring binding).  The presence of a few mis-matches doesn't mean a primer can never bind, it means that the temperature at which the hybridized primer/dsDNA pair dissociates (the "melting temperature") is lower than for a fully-matching primer.

Comment: Your explanation for single-stranded templates seems a little off, if the forward primer binds to the single-strand, the template won't contain the reverse-compliment sequence of the reverse primer, it will contain the same sequence as the reverse primer. The reverse primer will bind to the new strand of DNA synthesized by your first round of PCR.

Comment: I agree I worded that inartfully.  The "binding site" of a primer is the rc of the primer sequence, so technically I think I was right when I said the ssDNA will contain the rc of the binding site (aka the rc of the rc of the primer sequence, aka the primer sequence) but yes that is very confusingly worded.  I'll edit to improve.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of a specific answer to the questions you have asked, Curt F. has provided an excellent answer. I just want to provide you with a couple of extra resources to start you off reading about PCR mutagenesis.

Pages 3 and 4 of this manual give an intro to QuikChange plasmid mutagenesis using PCR and primers with small mismatches: http://www.chem.agilent.com/library/usermanuals/Public/200523.pdf

This page gives an intro on introducing restriction sites to the end of a DNA sequence being amplified by PCR: https://www.addgene.org/plasmid-protocols/PCR-cloning/

Comment: This is probably more suitable as a comment as it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: That's true, but the information hadn't been provided, and I'm too new to this particular subsection of stackexchange to comment. Would have if I could have.

Comment: There is long running confusion on this site about what "the question" is.  If you were to go by the title "Confusion about PCR", Michael's very nice answer does indeed "answer" it.  If you were to go by the random sentences that end in "?" which appear in the main text, I suppose the other guys have a point.  For this particular "question", the "?" sentences made sense and were easy to understand, but for many other questions they aren't.  So +1 from me to Michael's answer, and Michael, welcome to the site!